# Displaying variable sets that define each row

Tags: stata

To say that a dataset is (`person`, `year`) level means that each row of that dataset has different (`person`, `year`) like this:

```
person  year  wage
  Mike   2000   10
  Mike   2010   30
  Jack   1990   20
```

How can I make Stata display exactly those (`person`, `year`) variable sets that uniquely define each row?

I want to make a log file to record

```
person year
```

only, but not display any individual information (displaying individuals' information in a log file is against the rules set by the data provider).

How could I do this?

What I thought about is using `bysort` in some way

```
bysort person year: gen num=_n
```

and if every `num` is 1, then it means (`person`, `year`) defines each row.

But if a dataset is extremely large, then checking whether every `num` is 1 is too tedious. Is there any smarter way?

Comment: Lack of research is evident. Just skimming through the [D] Data management manual would identify relevant commands. Also, Stata has many FAQs on its website.

Comment: In Stata rows are called _observations_. I guess you would not ask an Excel question using the term _observations_, and the converse follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `isid` checks whether the variables you supply do jointly specify observations uniquely. Here is an example you can try:

```
. webuse grunfeld, clear

. isid company
variable company does not uniquely identify the observations
r(459);

. isid company year
```

Note the principle: no news is good news.

Another way to check for problems is through `duplicates`. For example, try `duplicates list person year`. In your case, you don't want that in the log. But what you can do first is anonymise your `person`s through

```
egen id = group(person)
```

and then check for duplicates on `id year`.

See also [this FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-group-identifiers/).